# How to Add an option to display dimensions in both cm and inch in the Additional information tab in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

[image: Add 2 types of measurements]

My client wants to display the cards that are sold as product both in cm and in inch. How can I do it?
[image: Like this]